# Processing database query in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's the correct way to process information from a database query after it has been retrieved.

Assuming the the below example that dataObj is just a js object that contains a field, name, which is defined, is this how I should be processing data in node.js?

EDIT:

forgot to mention that of course I can't return the data object because this is an async call.

```
function processData(dataObj){
    if(dataObj.name == "CS"){
        console.log("true");
    }
}

function getData(anon)
    var dat = .... sql query that works and its an object now that works correctly...
    anon(dat);
}

getData(processData);
```

Comment: What database are you using? What API does it present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet of some code i'm working on using mongoose:

```
    var db = mongoose.createConnection(uristring)
    , mongoose = require('mongoose');

    db.once('open', function(){

    var recipientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            username: String,
            recipientEmail: String
    });

    var Recipient = db.model('Recipient', recipientSchema);
    Recipient.find( {username: user }, function(err, recipients){   
      res.json(recipients);
    })
 })
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

One of NodeJS' strengths is streaming support. I would expect from a proper SQL driver to give me one row at the time. If I want I can collect all of them, but most of the time I don't want all the rows in memory. Instead I would stream them one by one to a consumer.

My preferred DB code would look like...

```
var db = require('<somedriver>');
var sqlStatement = ".... sql query that works and its an object now that works correctly...";

var query = db.execute(sqlStatement);

query.on('row', function (row) {
  // Do something with a row object...
  console.log("This is a row", row);
});

query.on('done', function (err, rowcount) {
  if (err) { throw err; } // or do something else...
  console.log("Number of rows received", rowcount)
});
```

Hope this helps